# How to use uiohook library in CMake project?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am trying to install the following C library:

https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook

I did the described steps which seem to work with no error.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook
$ cd uiohook
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake -S .. -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -D BUILD_DEMO=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../dist
$ cmake --build . --parallel 2 --target install
```

The problem is I don't know what to do next.

I tried to copy the code from the simple hook example and tried to execute the code in a different executable with the following `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(libuihook_test)


include_directories("/Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/include")
find_library(lib uiohook)

if(NOT lib)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "uiohook library not found")
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(libuihook_test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(libuihook_test lib)
```

which doesn't work and results in a

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (message):
  uiohook library not found
```

the log from installing is the following:

```
[ 14%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uiohook.dir/src/darwin/input_helper.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uiohook.dir/src/logger.c.o
[ 21%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uiohook.dir/src/darwin/input_hook.c.o
[ 28%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uiohook.dir/src/darwin/post_event.c.o
[ 35%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uiohook.dir/src/darwin/system_properties.c.o
[ 42%] Linking C shared library libuiohook.dylib
[ 42%] Built target uiohook
[ 57%] Building C object CMakeFiles/demo_post.dir/demo/demo_post.c.o
[ 57%] Building C object CMakeFiles/demo_properties.dir/demo/demo_properties.c.o
[ 71%] Linking C executable demo_properties
[ 71%] Linking C executable demo_post
[ 71%] Built target demo_post
[ 71%] Built target demo_properties
[ 78%] Building C object CMakeFiles/demo_hook.dir/demo/demo_hook.c.o
[ 85%] Building C object CMakeFiles/demo_hook_async.dir/demo/demo_hook_async.c.o
[ 92%] Linking C executable demo_hook
[100%] Linking C executable demo_hook_async
[100%] Built target demo_hook
[100%] Built target demo_hook_async
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/lib/libuiohook.1.2.0.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/lib/libuiohook.1.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/lib/libuiohook.dylib
-- Up-to-date: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/include/uiohook.h
-- Installing: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/lib/cmake/uiohook/uiohook-config.cmake
-- Installing: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/lib/cmake/uiohook/uiohook-config-noconfig.cmake
-- Installing: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/bin/demo_hook
-- Installing: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/bin/demo_hook_async
-- Installing: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/bin/demo_post
-- Installing: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/bin/demo_properties
-- Installing: /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/lib/pkgconfig/uiohook.pc
```

I consulted the CMAKE Docs but honestly right now confuses me more than it helps. I am sure at some point I will have an aha moment and connect the dots. Most tutorials do an excellent job of explaining you C/C++ but they all lack the more advanced stuff around build tools, testing, debugging, and so on, everything you basically need to build more complex projects. So I am also grateful for book/video suggestions.

I also tried different combinations of `include_directories`, add, link library also an absolute path but nothing seems to work and I get a library not found error or `uiohook.h` not found.

I am well aware that C and C++ are completely different languages and different practices apply I am not sure If I could have fixed this question to one. But basically try to learn C++ but need to access a lot of C libs.

Comment: See [Selecting static or shared libs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Selecting%20Static%20or%20Shared%20Libraries.html)

Comment: As far as linking with 3rd party libraries there's no differences between C and C++.

Comment: Please provide more detail than "doesn't work", is there an error? The build log from when you installed should show where it installed to

Comment: As you can see from the log, the library is installed at `/Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/lib/libuiohook.dylib`. Knowing its path you could link with it using e.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550334/3440745).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the library provides a `uiohook-config.cmake` you should use that to link to the library via [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) rather than using `find_library`.

Something like this should work:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /Users/ahoehne/libuiohook/dist/lib/cmake/uiohook/)
find_package(uiohook REQURIED)
target_link_libraries(libuihook_test uiohook)
```